# « Y s'jett'nt su' la porte en hurlant » : transcription du parler populaire ?

Tags: prononciation, oral, argot

> *Impressions de promenade* (extrait)
>
> [...] Leur conscienc' dit : « Tu t' soign's les tripes,
>  « Tu t'les
>   bourr's à t'en étouffer,
>  « Ben, n'en v'là un qu'a pas bouffé
>   !
>  Alors dame ! euss y m' prenn'nt en grippe !
>
> Gn'a pas ! mon spectr' les embarrasse,
>  Ça leur z'y donn' comm'
>   des remords :
>  Des fois, j'plaqu' ma fiole à leurs glaces,
>  Et
>   y d'viennent livid's comm' des morts !
>
> Du coup, malgré leur chair de poule,
>  Y s'jett'nt su' la porte en
>   hurlant :
>  Faut voir comme y z'ameut'nt la foule
>  Pendant
>   qu'Bibi y fout son camp ! [...]
>
> [ Gabriel Randon de Saint-Amand ([Jehan-Rictus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehan-Rictus)), (1867-1933), [Les
>   soliloques du pauvre](https://books.google.com/books?id=nqDw23WYAj0C&lpg=PA26&dq=rictus%20%22faut%20voir%20comme%20y%22&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q=%22faut%20voir%20comme%20y%22&f=false) (1897) ]

On mentionne que l'auteur est « célèbre pour ses œuvres composées dans la langue du peuple du Paris de son époque » (Wikipédia). On n'a pas trouvé de sens particulier pour la [*fiole*](https://archive.org/stream/DictionnaireDeLaLangueVerte/Dictionnaire_de_la_langue_verte#page/n221/mode/2up) dans le *Dictionnaire de la langue verte* (Delvau, 1889), reste qu'on observe divers procédés pour transcrire le parler populaire...

---

- Quelles sont les principaux procédés utilisés pour transcrire la
  langue populaire à l'écrit en ce qui a trait à la prononciation, et
  qu'on trouve, ou non, dans l'extrait ; quels sont les noms des phénomènes qu'ils représentent, en quoi consistent-ils généralement et quelles en sont les contraintes (à l'écrit) ?
- Un locuteur de Paris qui veut rendre la langue populaire
  d'aujourd'hui aura-t-il recours aux mêmes procédés ; quelles seraient
  les différences le cas échéant ?
- Le texte serait-il (davantage, moins) compris s'il était entendu plutôt que lu ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Le procédé le plus largement utilisé ici est la contraction  d'un certain nombre de syllabes "faibles" (*Tu te les >>> Tu t'les*), mais on constate aussi l'utilisation de termes argotiques ou populaires (*manger >>> bouffer*). A noter aussi, des liaisons et conjugaisons "volontairement" fautives mais plus ou moins idiomatiques (*Ca leur z'y donne*).
- Non, le parler populaire d'aujourd'hui a beaucoup évolué et ne ressemble plus du tout à celui de l'exemple cité. Les différences sont très nombreuses, il faudrait réécrire le texte car la simple substitution de quelques termes remis à jour ne sera vraisemblablement pas suffisante. Notamment, Les contractions sont toujours d'actualité mais ne seront pas toujours faites aux mêmes endroits, il y a aujourd'hui beaucoup de termes en verlan ou issus du verlan, et plus d'anglicismes.
- Il est effectivement plus facile, pour un locuteur de la langue habitué au parler courant, d'entendre ce texte que de le lire.

Comment: J'ajouterais au parler popu d'aujourd'hui la grande influence de termes ayant leur origine hors de la langue française, à la fois par la grande mixité des populations issues de l'immigration, et par l'influence de la culture, spécifiquement musicale et/ou publicitaire venue de la culture anglo saxonne - que tu mentionnes d'ailleurs. Par ailleurs il me semble qu'il y a eu au cours de ces 50 dernières années une certaine uniformisation du parler popu sur le territoire, le lexique tendant à s'uniformiser peut-être plus vite que l'accent ? (juste une question que je me pose).

Comment: Il y a aussi l'élision de "il >>> y" ou "ils >>> y (z')" qui sont toujours très courants.

Comment: On peut aussi noter que si l'auteur s'efforce à transcrire ces contractions si fidèlement, c'est sûrement parce que c'est un poème dans lequel les contractions sont essentielles au respect des exigences métriques...

Comment: Merci bien intéressant ! Peut-on svp. me donner un exemple précis d'un cas de contraction, peut-être d'un mot dans le texte, qu'on sent qu'on découperait différemment aujourd'hui. Mieux, peut-on présenter quelques mots d'un auteur particulier qui en feraient foi ?

Comment: @qoba Merci, bon point. Selon vous quel pourcentage de ces contractions sont dues à la métrique ?

Comment: @Laure Merci. Pouvez-vous détailler quelles sont les caractéristiques de cette uniformisation ; vers quoi tend-elle ?

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ en prose je n'imagine pas quelqu'un transcrire les élisions de e qui sont déjà normalement muets comme *soign's*, *jett'nt*, *bourr's*, *spectr'*, *donn'*, *plaqu'*, *ameut'nt*, parce que ça alourdit la lecture pour rien puisque c'est déjà à peu près comme ça que ces mots se prononcent dans le français "standard".

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ Par exemple, plutôt que *"Pendant qu'Bibi y fout son camp !"*, aujourd'hui il me semble qu'on dirait plutôt *"Pendant qu'Bibi fout l'camp !"*